# RSA Ciphering with JavaScript and Deciphering with php openssl

Tags: javascript, php

I'm doing a login system.
I want a client to cipher(with his private key) a random message coming from the server and send the result to the server. The server will then decipher the message with the public key and make a comparison.

I have tried jsencrypt. I have a cipher result but i can't use the openssl_public_decrypt to decrypt but it is not working

Please for advise or help!!!

Here is the file where the javascript ciphering is done

```
<?php


//Génération d'un message aleatoires
$i = 4;
global $bytes;
$bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($i, $cstrong);
$hex = pack('H*', bin2hex($bytes));;
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Accueil</title>
    <script language="javascript">
    function controle(form1, n) {
        if(n == 0){
            var pub = document.form1.clepub.value;
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            // 2=overwrite, true=create if not exist, 0 = ASCII
            var varFileObject = fso.OpenTextFile(pub, 1, false, 0);
            //varFileObject.write("File handling in Javascript");
            var s = varFileObject.ReadAll();
            varFileObject.close();
            return s;
        }
        else{
            var priv = document.form1.clepriv.value;
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            // 2=overwrite, true=create if not exist, 0 = ASCII
            var varFileObject = fso.OpenTextFile(priv, 1, false, 0);
            //varFileObject.write("File handling in Javascript");
            var s = varFileObject.ReadAll();
            varFileObject.close();
            return s;
        }
        //alert("La clé privée est : " + s);
    }
</script>
<script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jsencrypt-master/bin/jsencrypt.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
  function chiffrer()  {
        document.getElementById("testme").style.visibility="hidden";
      // Encrypt with the public key...
      var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
      encrypt.setPublicKey(controle(form1, 1));
      //alert(controle(form1, 1));
      var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt("'.$hex.'");

      document.getElementById("submit").style.visibility="visible";

      document.getElementById("input").value = encrypted;
      //alert(encrypted);
      //document.getElementById("input").value = encryptedb64tohex(encrypted);
  }
</script>';
echo '</head>
<body>
<h1>Bienvenue sur TelGov</h1>
<h2>Engager votre clef privee</h2>
<form  action="compare.php" method="POST" name = "form1">
    <!--<label for="clepub">Engager votre clef publique</label>
    <input name="clepub" id="clepub" type="file"></input>
    <label for="clepriv">Engager votre clef privee</label>-->
    <input name="clepriv" id="clepriv" type="file"></input>
    <br/><br/>
    <input name="hash" id="hash" type="hidden" value="'.$hex.'"></input>
    <br/><br/>
    <input id="input" name="input" type="hidden" ></input><br/>
    <input id="testme" type="button" value="Engager" onclick="chiffrer()" /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="'.$username.'">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="'.$password.'">
    <!--<br/><br/>
    <input type="button" name="bouton" value="Controler" onClick="controle(form1)">
    <br/><br/>-->
    <input type="submit" id = "submit" value="Se connecter" style="visibility: hidden;"</input>
</form>
</body>

</html>';
```

?>

Here is the  code for comparison

```
<?php

try{
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=authentification', 'root', '');
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$config = array(
                    "config" => "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/openssl.cnf",
                    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
                    "private_key_bits" => 1024,
                    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
                );

if(isset($_POST['input'])&&isset($_POST['hash'])){
    $crypt = $_POST['input'];
    $bon = $_POST['hash'];

    $cle = $bdd->prepare("SELECT publicKey FROM utilisateurs WHERE username =? AND password=?");
    $cle->execute(array($username, $password));
    $tmp = $cle->fetch();
    var_dump($tmp['publicKey']);
    var_dump($bon);
    //var_dump(openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($crypt), $decrypted, $tmp['privateKey']/*openssl_pkey_get_private($tmp['privateKey'], null)*/));
    var_dump(openssl_public_decrypt (base64_decode($crypt)/*$crypt*/, $decryted, $tmp['publicKey']));
    var_dump($decryted);
    var_dump(base64_decode($crypt));
    if($decryted == $bon){
        //header("Location:Accueil.php");
        echo "Bon";
    }
    else{
        //header("Location:index.php");
        echo "Mauvais";
    }

}
else{
    header("Location:index.php");
}
```

?>

Here is the comparison result

[Image result from IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0cz1.png)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Can you advise me something?

Comment: I have tried jsencrypt. I have a cipher result but i can't use the openssl_public_decrypt to decrypt but it is not working

Comment: What is not working? Show us an example.

Comment: Provide your code on both sides, as well as any error logs, a sample of data to be encrypted/decrypted, the key you use, the resulting encrypted data, the resulting decrypted data, and any other relevant details. "It is not working" is about as useful as you telling your doctor "it hurts" without providing any further details.

Comment: OK. Please just a moment!!!

Comment: If what you need is to securly transfer a password to a server just use HTTPS, it is that simple and it is secure.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Jsencrypt library.
I have found that it is not possible to encrypt with the private key with Jsencrypt and decrypt with the public key with php openssl.
So i have changed my method and i have used the encryption with the public key with Jsencrypt an the decryption with php openssl. This work very well

Comment: By design encryption is dome with the public key and decryption with the private key. Consider, if the public key was used for decryption everyone could decrypt the message since the public key is not secret. But perhaps you do not need a key pair (the usual case), just a single secret key for both encryption and decryption, if so use a symmetric encryption such as AES which has speed, simplicity and unlimited data length advantages.

Answer (score -2):

I find this jsencrypt library (http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt), after 2 days trying I got my solution.

The only problem I got is when I send a long text. That's because RSA, by definition, supports strings of limited lenght.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security/33445#33445

> RSA, as defined by PKCS#1, encrypts "messages" of limited size. With
>   the commonly used "v1.5 padding" and a 2048-bit RSA key, the maximum
>   size of data which can be encrypted with RSA is 245 bytes. No more.

i.e.
If I use private_key_bits of 1024 I can send

```
"José compró en Perú una vieja zampoña. Excusándose, Sofía tiró su whisky al desagüe de la banqueta."
```

nothing longer.
If I use private_key_bits of 512 I can send

```
"José compró en Perú una vieja zampoña. Excusánd"
```

nothing longer.

On long strings JavaScript console reports: "Message too long for RSA"

Then if you want to encrypt long strings you must compress and split them before javascript encryption and after decryption join and uncompress on php, I think zlib is a good solution for split/join because it is supported on javascript and php.

My working code is as follows:

```
<?php
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Global Settings.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $directorio = "/path/to/key/directory/apache/writable/";
    $nombre_base = "llaves_php";

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialization.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    $encabezado_html = "";
    $cuerpo_html = "";

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Loading keys
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    list($privateKey, $pubKey) =
        cargar_llaves_RSA($directorio, $nombre_base);

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Form that uses javascript to encrypt data.
    // (it uses only the public key)
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    $librerias_html = "
        <script type='text/javascript'
                src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/".
                    "jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'
                src='lib/jsencrypt.js'></script>
        ";

    $pubKey_html = htmlentities($pubKey);
    $datos_html = "
        <h2>Cifrando con Javascript</h2>
        <input type='text' id='mensaje' />
        <br />
        <button id='ENVIAR'>Enviar</button>
        <br />
        <textarea id='pubkey' style='display: none;'>".
        $pubKey_html.
        "</textarea>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('#ENVIAR').click(function () {
                var codificador = new JSEncrypt();
                codificador.setKey($('#pubkey').val());
                var cifrado = codificador.encrypt($('#mensaje').val());
                window.open('?mensaje=' + encodeURIComponent(cifrado)
                           , '_top');
            });
        </script>
        ";

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Decrypting using php (it uses only the privateKey)
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    if (isset($_REQUEST['mensaje'])) {
        openssl_private_decrypt( base64_decode($_REQUEST['mensaje'])
                               , $descifrado
                               , $privateKey);
        $datos_html.= "
            <h2>Descifrando con PHP</h2>
            ".$descifrado."
            ";
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // HTML DISPLAY
    //------------------------------------------------------------
    $encabezado_html.= "<title>Receptor de mensaje cifrado</title>"
                     . $librerias_html;

    $cuerpo_html.= $datos_html;

    $contenido = "<head>$encabezado_html</head><body>$cuerpo_html</body>";
    $contenido = "<html>$contenido</html>";
    print $contenido;

//============================================================
//============================================================
// Functions
//============================================================
//============================================================

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    function cargar_llaves_RSA($directorio, $nombre_base) {
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // PROPÓSITO: Genera o carga desde archivos las llaves RSA
    // ENTRADAS:
    // $directorio: Directorio donde se encuentran los archivos.
    // $nombre_base: Nombre, sin extensión, de los archivos con
    //               las llaves.
    // SALIDAS:
    //------------------------------------------------------------
        if (  !file_exists($directorio.$nombre_base.".crt")
           || !file_exists($directorio.$nombre_base.".pub")) {
            list($privateKey, $pubKey) = crear_llaves_RSA($directorio.$nombre_base);
        } else {
            //------------------------------------------------------------
            // CARGA DE LLAVES RSA ARCHIVADAS
            //------------------------------------------------------------
            $privateKey = file_get_contents($directorio.$nombre_base.".crt");
        if (!$privKey = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey))
            die('Loading Private Key failed');
            $pubKey  = file_get_contents($directorio.$nombre_base.".pub");
        }

    return array($privateKey, $pubKey);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    function crear_llaves_RSA($ruta_base) {
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // PROPÓSITO:
    // generacion de llaves RSA en php
    // ENTRADAS:
    // $ruta_base: Ruta de los archivos a generar sin extensión.
    // SALIDAS:
    // Se generarán dos archivos, uno con la llave privada con
    // extensión .crt, el otro con llave pública con extensión
    // .pub; la función retorna tanto la llave pública como la
    // privada en un arreglo.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
        $config = array(
            "private_key_bits" => 1024,
            "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
        );

        $llavePrivadaCruda = openssl_pkey_new($config);
        openssl_pkey_export_to_file($llavePrivadaCruda, $ruta_base.".crt");
        $privateKey = file_get_contents($ruta_base.".crt");
        openssl_pkey_export($llavePrivadaCruda, $privKey);

        $pubKeyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($llavePrivadaCruda);
        $pubKey = $pubKeyData["key"];
        file_put_contents($ruta_base.".pub", $pubKey);
        openssl_free_key($llavePrivadaCruda);

    return array($privateKey, $pubKey);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    function Mostrar($valor) {
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // PROPÓSITO: Genera el código HTML para presentar una
    // variable embebida en la página.
    // ENTRADAS:
    // $valor: el valor a presentar.
    // SALIDAS: código html que permite visualizar la variable.
    //------------------------------------------------------------
        $retorno = htmlentities(stripslashes(var_export($valor, true)));
        $retorno = "<pre>$retorno</pre>";
        return $retorno;
    }

?>
```

Directory tree must looks like:

```
├── script.php
└── lib
    └── jsencrypt.js
```

and a directory writable by php outside of public zone named

```
/path/to/key/directory/apache/writable/
```

---

Comment: 1. This is not an answer to the question. 2. This is **not** the way to send long messages with RSA, RSA is not designed for that, either use symmetric encryption such as AES or if a key-pair is required use hybrid encryption which encrypts the data with symmetric encryption with a random key, encrypts the key with RSA and packages they together. See [Hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). 3. Please don't try and invent your own cryptography, use well vetted methods.